# Get configuration settings not working

Tags: 8, configuration

I am writing [this](https://github.com/shabirmanu/Flood-Control) Drupal 8 module. I am setting up some configuration settings [here](https://github.com/shabirmanu/Flood-Control/blob/master/config/install/flood_control.settings.yml)

But when I retrieve it [here](https://github.com/shabirmanu/Flood-Control/blob/master/src/Form/SettingsForm.php) using `$this->config()->get()` it is not giving anything. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `flood_control.settings.yml`.

```
flood_control:
  user_failed_login_ip_limit: 50
  ...
```

This way, to get `user_failed_login_ip_limit` you must use `$this->config(flood_control.settings)->get('flood_control.user_failed_login_ip_limit')`. Or just remove `flood_control:` on first line for better use.

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid enough to not include the schema for the settings. I have made it working by including schema file like [this](https://github.com/shabirmanu/Flood-Control/tree/master/config).